# Generate random number in a range [0, n) in C?

Tags: c, random, numbers

Looking to make a really simple random number generator method in C. The numbers should be between 0 and 24 and can be for example 14.5f.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
float getRand() {
  float rnd = rand();
  rnd /= RAND_MAX;
  return rnd * 24.0f;
}
```

Make sure you seed the random number generator with `srand` before use.

Comment: Note that rand is deprecated on some platforms (OS X, Ubuntu 8.04) in favour of the random, srandom, etc functions.

Comment: Seed before everytime its called? Also seed with what exactly?

Comment: No... absolutely not every time. Just once before the first call. You can seed with srand(time(0));

Comment: @Dana: it's not comparable, only rand() is part of C.

Comment: The functions are equivalent on newer systems, but for anything previous you should be accounting for the low order bit issue with rand(). We should be providing the best answer for any readers who use this question in the future.

Comment: See the Notes section http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/rand.3.html

Comment: No rand() I've encountered on a recent system (no, not even MSVC) actually uses the lower bits of the generator's state word.

Comment: Not to mention that the code presented in this answer uses as many significant bits as it can from rand()'s return value, and would be as immune to the low bits problem as possible if rand() did return the low bits in a bad implementation.

Answer (score 4):

The [Mersenne_twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) is not only very simple, but also very strong.

See the code on the link.

However, if you can use [GPL License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License), use the [The GNU Scientific Library (GSL)](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) specific check [Random-Number-Generator-Examples](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-Number-Generator-Examples.html)
from [Random-Number-Generation part of the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-Number-Generation.html)

There are many things there, from simple uniform random numbers to other distributions.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [linear congruential generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), they are quite simple to implement even with my inferior math knowledge.

*Looks like I misunderstood the original question, I thought you wanted to roll your own generator (for homework, fun etc.)*

Answer (score 3):

You can use C's built in random number generator to get an integer between 0 and 30 thousand something like this:

```
`srand(time(NULL));
    int x= rand();`
```

You would just need to do some division to get a decimal number instead of and integer.

Comment: Note that rand is deprecated on some platforms (OS X, Ubuntu 8.04) in favour of the random, srandom, etc.