# Creating own random generator in C

Tags: c, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple random number generator C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766005/simple-random-number-generator-c)

Can someone post links that you know of that help in understanding the creation of a user-defined random number generator in C. I lack the basic idea of how a random number generator works.Posting the logic will help too.

Comment: This Wiki page has some information on the working of a random number generator: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator. Also this: http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: Should i delete this question as you found it a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point for a pseudo-random number generator try looking at [linear feedback shift registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register)

Here is a simple implementation of a 4 bit LFSR in c:

```
char lfsr(char unshifted)
{
    char ret = 0;

    if( ( unshifted & 0x01 ) ^ ( ( unshifted & 0x02 ) >> 1) )
    {
        ret = (unshifted >> 1);
        ret = (ret | 0x08);
    }
    else
    {
        ret = (unshifted >> 1);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Because the register has a finite number of possible states, it must eventually enter a repeating cycle. However, an LFSR with a well-chosen feedback function can produce a sequence of bits which appears random and which has a very long cycle.